# Inject argument into npm script command

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an npm script that looks like:

```
"scripts": {
    "example": "webpack-dev-server --content-base examples/embeddable/"
},
```

I'd like to form the `--content-base` argument dynamically based on whatever's passed when calling the npm script, like:

```
npm run example -- embeddable
```

I know the `--` syntax works for making args available to `process.argv`, but I'm not calling a Node script here so I'm not sure how to access them when forming the command. Does anyone else know of a good, cross-platform way to do this? (Must work on Windows 7, i.e. without bash capabilities.)

Answer (score 0):

This should work ($1 is replaced by whatever you add as first parameter):

```
"scripts": {
    "example": "webpack-dev-server --content-base examples/${1}/"
},
```

Run it like this:

```
npm run example -- embeddable
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I had a similar idea but wasn't sure if it would work on Windows (which is a requirement, unfortunately.) Do you have any idea if this will port?

Comment: Hmm… I don't know, I'm a Mac user myself. I've tried it out on my machine with `"scripts" : { "example": "echo $1" } }`, and it worked fine. But doesn't Windows 10 now have a proper unix-like shell?

Comment: I think you're right about Windows 10, but we're a generation or two behind where I work :P I just gave this a try on my Mac -- it seems to take `embeddable` and append it to the entire command (in addition to the `--content-base` flag), which causes `webpack-dev-server` to look in the wrong place. I'll keep playing with it though!

Comment: try putting the number 1 in curly braces (updated code example)

Comment: Hm, still getting the same result

Comment: Dollar sign, curly braces, hyphens or not, I'm not getting any replacement. It just runs the function with the parameter tagged onto the end. Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Terminal